# string concatenation in css

Tags: html, css

I want to achieve the following in css. How do i do it in a cross browser way?

```
url('../img/icons/' + attr('type') + '_10.png')
```

Comment: @zzzzBov how do i do this [class^="connection-"]::after

Comment: Can you phrase that in the form of a question? I'm not sure what you're asking me here.

Comment: @zzzzBov How can i use ::after along with [] selector

Comment: `[type="foo"]:after { style: value; }`, basically as you'd shown, which is why I was confused by the question. Did you try it before asking?

Comment: @zzzzBov yes the one that i had was not not working let me try with single ':' instead of double '::'.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't do dynamic string interpolation in the way that you're suggesting, but if you have a limited number of possible values for the `[type]` attribute, you could create styles for each one:

```
.your .selector[type="foo"] {
    background-image: url('../img/icons/foo_10.png');
}
.your .selector[type="bar"] {
    background-image: url('../img/icons/bar_10.png');
}
.your .selector[type="baz"] {
    background-image: url('../img/icons/baz_10.png');
}
```

If you've got an unreasonable number of types, then you'll probably need to come up with a better solution than I've listed here.

Answer (score 30):

I don't think you can. In the `content` property you can "concatenate" just by separating with a space, but in other places I don't think there is such a feature. Which is a shame.

You'll probably be best off specifying this style in a `style` attribute whenever the `type` attribute is used.

Comment: I believe this is coming in the specification, just not supported in any browser yet. https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/CSS/attr#Browser_Compatibility

Comment: @Fabrício Matté: Unfortunately this is an issue with url() and not with attr() regardless of browser support, and it may never be possible unless they re-spec url(). See my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42932294/css-attr-concatenation-with-url-path/42932766#42932766

Comment: `you can "concatenate" just by separating with a space` That's what we're looking for.

Comment: you can concatenate `content` property by separating with a space. eg: `content: 'Page: ' counter(page);`

Answer (score 4):

No, you can't do this in plain CSS because the CSS language hasn't control structures or anything like that wich will allow you to dinamically generate CSS code.

Instead, you can use a javascript solutions or a solution based on CSS variables coded in PHP.

Answer (score 3):

CSS performs **concatenation** without using any operator (e.g. +, &, etc). Keep your strings in quotes combine the strings, attr, var, etc into one line.

Examples:

- `url('not/very' '/useful/concatenation'); // not/very/useful/concatentation`
- `url('../img/icons/' attr('type') '_10.png'); //../img/icons/${type}_10.png`
- `url(attr('href') '#hash'); // https://${href}/#hash`
- `url(var(--hello) ' world'); // Hello World`

Comment: **From review queue**: May I request you to please add some more context around your answer. Code-only answers are difficult to understand. It will help the asker and future readers both if you can add more information in your post.

Comment: Incredible that CSS uses space \20 as a concatenation operator. 

Comment: I wonder if the author actually tried those examples. It seems it is not possible, at least with the var() example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42330075/is-there-a-way-to-interpolate-css-variables-with-url

Comment: This does not work in Firefox and shows as invalid CSS.

Comment: This suggestion doesn't seem to work in Chrome either. At least I tested it with a concatenation in `url()` for an image base url kinf of thing: https://codepen.io/astaco/pen/VwyQwrz

Comment: I wonder how this answer could get so many upvotes. The first and last point don't work (tried in the provided codepen) and after reading the background from the other comment I believe the other two shouldn't work either. This is just impossible today. (PS: Most of the answer was edited in later, not all is from the first author!)

Comment: Sadly, the last example `url(var(--hello) ' world')` doesn't work, as `var()` cannot be interpolated inside `url()`… See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42330075/is-there-a-way-to-interpolate-css-variables-with-url).

Comment: I'm sure this is a wrong answer. Those case all do not work as my test.

Comment: according to spec one can use src() instead of url() to do such
https://drafts.csswg.org/css-values/#urls

Answer (score 0):

I can provide a solution to concatenate strings for the CSS URL property without considering the attr('type') of each element, and here is an example:

```js
// You can convert all the paths to be in your desired paths format in JS: 
let rootElement = document.querySelector('#my-root-element');
for (const [prop, val] of rootElement.computedStyleMap()){ 
  if (prop.startsWith('--var-')) {
var updatedValue = `url("${'../img/icons/' + val}")`;
console.log(updatedValue);
rootElement.style.setProperty(prop, updatedValue);
  }
};

for (const child of rootElement.children) {
  child.textContent = window.getComputedStyle(child).getPropertyValue('background-image');
}
```

```css
/* In your CSS, you can define some variables like this: */
#my-root-element{
  --var-a: btn_10a.png;
  --var-a-img: img_10a.png;
  --var-b: btn_10b.png;
  --var-c: btn_10c.png;
  --var-d: btn_10d.png;
}

#my-button-a{
  background-image: var(--var-a);
}

#my-button-a-img[type="img"]{
  background-image: var(--var-a-img);
}

#my-button-b{
  background-image: var(--var-b);
}

#my-button-c{
  background-image: var(--var-c);
}

.my-button{
  display: block;
  margin: 10px;
}

div#my-button-a-img{
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<!-- Let's say your HTML is like this: --> 
<div id="my-root-element">
  <button class="my-button" id="my-button-a" type="button"></button>
  <div class="my-button" id="my-button-a-img" type="img"></div>
  <button class="my-button" id="my-button-b" type="button"></button>
  <button class="my-button" id="my-button-c" type="button"></button>
<div>
```

Here is the link of the pen: https://codepen.io/lerner-zhang/pen/dyaOOmQ?editors=1111