# Appending a CSS function (calc) to a string (url)?

Tags: css

I have div that is parented to a div with 100% width. The child div has its width set to `calc(20% - 10px)`. Now what I want to do is use [placehold.it](http://placehold.it) to give it a temporary background image. Is it possible to append a CSS3 function to a string like this?

```
background-image: url("http://placehold.it/" + calc(20% - 10px) + "x790");
```

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15745492/string-concatenation-in-css

Comment: CSS Calc only works with numbered fields. It can be used in background-position, width, height etc. But it cant work in conjunction with text and it wont process