# CSS Variables and String concatenation

Tags: css, webpack, css-variables

I'm trying to use CSS variables to generate a dynamic path.

**Example**:

```
:root {
  --fonts-path: "/path/to/font";
}

@font-face {
  font-family: "FontName";
  src: url(var(--fonts-path) + "/FontName-Light.woff") format('woff');
  font-weight: 100;
}

html {
  font-family: 'Metric', Arial, sans-serif;
}
```

This is failing with a not-found module `'var(--hpe-fonts-path'`, this is the webpack log:

```
ERROR in ./~/css-loader?sourceMap&modules&importLoaders=1&localIdentName=[name]__[local]___[hash:base64:5]!./~/postcss-loader!./src/theme/fonts.css
Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve module 'var(--fonts-path' in /Users/project-sample/src/theme
 @ ./~/css-loader?sourceMap&modules&importLoaders=1&localIdentName=[name]__[local]___[hash:base64:5]!./~/postcss-loader!./src/theme/fonts.css 6:83-114 6:234-265 6:403-434 6:576-607
```

Any pointers?

Answer (score 10):

I see some problems with your approach:

- `@font-face` rules don't inherit CSS variables set on `:root`.
- You can't use `+` to concatenate CSS strings. See [string concatenation in css](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15745492/1529630)
- Not all implementations support `var()` inside `url()` yet.

Answer (score 7):

You can combine a variable with a unit like this:

```css
:root {
  --twenty: 20;
}
.box {
  width: calc( var(--twenty) * 1px );
  height: calc( var(--twenty) * 1px );
}
```

```html
<div class="box" style="background:red;"></div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Try incluiding the url inside the variable, This works in a background context, but not sure if it does inside font-face

```
:root { 
--url:url("https://picsum.photos/id/1/200/300"); 
}

.box { 
background:var(--url); 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

A similar issue is described in this post:

[CSS native variables not working in media queries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40722882/css-native-variables-not-working-in-media-queries)

where the user tries to use a variable inside a @font-face rule.

As described in the accepted answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/40723269/4879632) you cannot use variables inside of rules, because the variables are inherited by :root (html) child elements. @ Rules (font faces, media queries, etc) are not elements, so they do not inherit from the root. Thus, you cannot reference a variable from there.

Answer (score 0):

You can't concatenate variable in CSS ([refer here](https://codepen.io/hidanielle/post/css-variables-an-introduction)):

> Since you can't concatenate in CSS (aside from the content property), CSS variables can not be concatenated. This means, for example, you can't combine a CSS variable that is a number with a unit.
>
> ```
> // No version of this will work 
> div {
>   --height: 100;
>   height: var(--height) + 'px';
> }
> ```

Answer (score 0):

You Should Do it like this to concat some variable using after value in css variable

```
:root{
  --scroll:0;
  --scrollunit:1deg;
}

.someclass{

    rotate:calc(var(--scroll) * var(--scrollunit));

}
```

https://codepen.io/abhishek-bhardwaj/pen/VwVyrmb