# Is there a way to interpolate CSS variables with url()?

Tags: css, css-variables

I want to store my background URLs in custom properties (CSS variables) and use them with the background property. However, I couldn't find a way to interpolate the string when using it as a parameter in `url()`.

Here is my sample code:

```
:root {
    --url: "https://download.unsplash.com/photo-1420708392410-3c593b80d416";
}

body {
    background: url(var(--url));
}
```

I know that this can be easily done in Sass or LESS using the interpolation function but I'm curious if there is a way to do it without any pre-processor.

Comment: You were so close, `--url: url(yoururl);`  `background: var(--url);`

Comment: @pol: That's not close at all. That's missing the point of this question by a mile. Still, it *is* the only solution to the problem with respect to url().

Comment: @SharmaJ what kind of *new* answer are you looking for?

Comment: @TemaniAfif I can't be *entirely* sure the OP had the same point to the question as what brought me here, but I was hoping to do this:

`:root {
    --url: "https://example.com/images";
}

body {
    background: url(var(--url)/bg1.jpg);
}
#wrapper {
    background: url(var(--url)/bg2.jpg);
}`
Unfortunately, it seems I'm reduced to either javascript or editing a gazillion lines of code between development and production environments. Oh well.

Answer (score 202, accepted):

You can perform interpolation with most CSS functions, including `rgba()` (see an example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40010597/how-do-i-apply-opacity-to-a-css-color-variable/41265350#41265350)). In fact, interpolation is one of the main features of custom properties.

But you cannot do this with `url()`, as `url(var(--url))` is parsed not as a `url(` function token followed by `var(--url)` followed by a `)`, but a single `url()` token that is invalid because the `var(--url)` is being treated as a URL itself, and unquoted URLs in `url()` tokens cannot contain parentheses unless they are escaped. This means the substitution never actually occurs, because the parser never sees any `var()` expressions in the property value — indeed, your `background` declaration is completely invalid.

If you didn't understand any of that, that's fine. Just know that you cannot use `var()` interpolation with `url()` due to legacy reasons.

Even though the problem depicted in the question is related to the legacy `url()` token, you cannot do this by building URL tokens out of several `var()` expressions either, in case you were thinking of trying something like `--uo: url(; --uc: );` or `--uo: url("; --uc: ");`, and `background: var(--uo) var(--url) var(--uc);`. This is because [custom properties cannot contain unmatched string delimiters or parts of `url()` tokens (called bad URL tokens)](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-variables-1/#syntax).

If you want to specify a URL in a custom property, you need to write out the entire `url()` expression, and substitute that entire expression:

```
:root {
  --url: url("https://download.unsplash.com/photo-1420708392410-3c593b80d416");
}

body {
  background: var(--url);
}
```

Or, use JavaScript instead of `var()` to perform the interpolation.

Comment: Got your point! @boltclock. I didn't know how url() is parsed and tokenized. If anyone else wants read further, here is a useful link - [typedef-url-token](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-syntax-3/#typedef-url-token).

Comment: Thanks for the great answer.  So sad that CSS designers did not address this use-case. :-(

Answer (score 4):

You cannot interpolate css variables with url but what you can do is to implement the url function as part of your variable like this:

```css
:root {
  --url: url("https://download.unsplash.com/photo-1420708392410-3c593b80d416");
}

body {
  background: var(--url);
}
```

in HTML could be:

```html
<div class="css_class_setting_background" style="--url: url('https://download.unsplash.com/photo-1420708392410-3c593b80d416');"> </div>
```

This works on most of modern browsers.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue on a project with Cordova so I used:

```
header{
  --bg-header: url(../img/header_home.png) left center/cover no-repeat;
  background: var(--bg-header,
      url("../img/header_home.png") left center/cover no-repeat
  );
}
```

Apparently, if you use **url("")** with double quotes on the **--var** declaration, the value will not work.

Comment: I keep getting Css Syntax Effor when I try to set this: url(PATH_WITH_OR_WITHOUT_QUOTES) as var value. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution which works in vue3

```
<script setup>
const backImage = ref("url(/img/imImage.webp)")
</script>

<style>
div {
  background-image: v-bind(backImage );
}
</style>
```

[Here](https://vuejs.org/api/sfc-css-features.html#v-bind-in-css) is the official Vuejs documentation.

Below ([playground link](https://play.vuejs.org/#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)) is the solution with both Vuejs and CSS custom properties:

```js
<script setup>
import { ref } from "vue"
  const divImage = ref("url('https://download.unsplash.com/photo-1696075619091-dedae25b1f65')")
</script>

<template>
  <div>Hello</div>
</template>

<style>
:root {
  --url: url("https://download.unsplash.com/photo-1420708392410-3c593b80d416");
}

body {
  background:  var(--url);
}

div {
  background:   v-bind(divImage);
}
</style>
```