# Is that possible to use css variable in css "background url"

Tags: css, background-image, css-variables, css-import

I would like to set a base domain with all of my pictures in CSS file, here's what I tried:

global.css

```
:root
{
  --bgd: #C0C0C0;
  --picdomain: "https://somedomain.com/";
}
```

s1.css

```
@import url("global.css");

body
{
  background-color: var(--bgd); //works if only it exist
  background: url(var(--picdomain)"some/path/images/pic.png"); //no effect
}
```

And load s1.css in html

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="s1.css">
```

The HTML's background-color did changed, but background didn't show up. So I tried other way:

global.css

```
@picdomain: "https://somedomain.com";
```

s1.css

```
background: url("@picdomain/some/path/images/pic.png");  //can't read variable from imported css
```

didn't help

Only works while I set full URL for an image, like below:

global.css

```
:root
{
  --bgd: #C0C0C0;
  --picdomain: url("https://somedomain.com/some/path/images/pic.png");
}
```

s1.css

```
@import url("global.css");

body
{
  background-color: var(--bgd); //works if only it exist
  background: var(--picdomain); //no effect
}
```

But this isn't what I want......Is that possible to use css variable in "background"?

Comment: hi i'm afraid youre not missing quotes in there right? not familiar with using css vars, but as far as i Know when you set a value for an attribute in css (like background url) isn't that you have to enclosed the value with quotes?

Comment: That was some type error while asking, I fixed in here and my code, but didn't work.

Comment: I see, anyway you can check this ticket anyway it might give you a hint to your issue. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42330075/is-there-a-way-to-interpolate-css-variables-with-url

Comment: It worked if I set full path & file name in variable, but not just domain name. Anyway, still thanks for your hint~

Comment: Yeah I also read that, but I did'nt think that it may reflect to your requirements since you only want to put the "domain" of your pics into that variable excluding the "path" so I assumed that you will be having different paths and images for each background, but same domain. anyway good to hear that it helped you somehow.

Answer (score -3):

```
    <style type="text/css">
    :root {
        --slide-1: url("{{url('public/assets/images/logo-nfs.png')}}"); /*this is laravel*/ 
        --slide-2: url("<?php echo 'images/logo-nfs.png';?>");  
    }`enter code here`

    .header111 {
      background-image : var(--slide-1); /*this is php*/ 
    }

    .header22 {
      background-image : var(--slide-2);
    }

    </style>

<div class="header111">
  test here 
</div>

<div class="header22">
  test here
</div>
<br>
```

Comment: Please add some explanation, don't dump just code as your entire answer.