# SVG fill with CSS variables

Tags: css, svg

I am trying to use CSS variables in my SVG (which is set as a background image) for the fill color, but am having difficulty in getting it to work. It shows the default black, but when I inspect it I can see that the css variable is there and showing my desired color.

HTML

```
<div class="test">
  Testing the css variable color
</div>

<div class="icon">

</div>
```

CSS

```
:root {
  --primary-color: hsl(332, 61%, 78%);
}

div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px; 
}

.test {
  background: var(--primary-color);
}

.icon {
  background: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' viewBox='0 0 129 129'%3E%3Cpath d='m121.3,34.6c-1.6-1.6-4.2-1.6-5.8,0l-51,51.1-51.1-51.1c-1.6-1.6-4.2-1.6-5.8,0-1.6,1.6-1.6,4.2 0,5.8l53.9,53.9c0.8,0.8 1.8,1.2 2.9,1.2 1,0 2.1-0.4 2.9-1.2l53.9-53.9c1.7-1.6 1.7-4.2 0.1-5.8z' fill='var(--primary-color)' /%3E%3C/svg%3E");
}
```

[Here is a codepen to check out!](https://codepen.io/sammiepls/pen/qyNMXj)

I've seen CSS Variables being used in SVG [here](https://frontstuff.io/multi-colored-svg-symbol-icons-with-css-variables) but I'm not sure if it's possible to do with background images? I'm new to both using SVG and CSS variables so I'm not sure if I'm doing something wrong... Would love some insight as to why it's not rendering the color properly!

Comment: Hey! Yes the background of the square is supposed to change color according to the CSS variable (primary-color). The SVG fill color is also supposed to change but in this case it's not. The square is just to show that the CSS variable color is being applied to it :)

Comment: no it's impossible, you cannot use CSS variable like this when it's called with URL

Comment: duplicate of : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42330075/is-there-a-way-to-interpolate-css-variables-with-url

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Okay here we go... I will first explain why it does not work and then I will show an alternative.

**Why your approach doesn't work**

In your example the svg is not part of the DOM. So you cannot use css to modify the attributes of the svg.

What you are doing is adding an inline-style to the svg in your url. Since the browser does not recognise `--primary-color` as a color it doesn't work.

**An alternative approach**

An alternative approach is to put the svg in the html and fake a background. I did this by absolute positioning the svg and moving it to the background with z-index.

Do note you will have to modify the svg or the positioning to place the background in the way you want. Normally you would use background-size for this. But with some effort you can replicate this behaviour within the svg or position it better by using css.

```css
:root {
  --primary-color: hsl(332, 61%, 78%);
}

div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px; 
}

.test {
  background: var(--primary-color);
}
.icon{ /*postion relative for absolute positioning to work*/
  position: relative; 
}
.icon>svg{
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
  z-index: -1;
}
.icon>svg>path{ /*target the image with css*/
  fill: var(--primary-color);
}
```

```html
<div class="test">
  Testing the css variable color
</div>

<div class="icon">
  <svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' viewBox='0 0 129 129' id='background'><path d='m121.3,34.6c-1.6-1.6-4.2-1.6-5.8,0l-51,51.1-51.1-51.1c-1.6-1.6-4.2-1.6-5.8,0-1.6,1.6-1.6,4.2 0,5.8l53.9,53.9c0.8,0.8 1.8,1.2 2.9,1.2 1,0 2.1-0.4 2.9-1.2l53.9-53.9c1.7-1.6 1.7-4.2 0.1-5.8z'/> </svg>
  <p>Text goes here...</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Very clear and helped me to understand why my CSS variables weren't working. Thanks for the example as well, unfortunately not sure if I could go this route as the reason I was trying to use the SVG as a background was to replace the select tag dropdown (aghh selects are so hard to work with!). But great explanation :)

Answer (score 40):

You can include the SVG as a `mask-image` instead of a `background-image`. Remember to set the `background-color` to the CSS variable for the `.icon` block.

```
.icon {
  background: var(--primary-color);
  -webkit-mask-image: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' viewBox='0 0 129 129'%3E%3Cpath d='m121.3,34.6c-1.6-1.6-4.2-1.6-5.8,0l-51,51.1-51.1-51.1c-1.6-1.6-4.2-1.6-5.8,0-1.6,1.6-1.6,4.2 0,5.8l53.9,53.9c0.8,0.8 1.8,1.2 2.9,1.2 1,0 2.1-0.4 2.9-1.2l53.9-53.9c1.7-1.6 1.7-4.2 0.1-5.8z' /%3E%3C/svg%3E");
  mask-image: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' viewBox='0 0 129 129'%3E%3Cpath d='m121.3,34.6c-1.6-1.6-4.2-1.6-5.8,0l-51,51.1-51.1-51.1c-1.6-1.6-4.2-1.6-5.8,0-1.6,1.6-1.6,4.2 0,5.8l53.9,53.9c0.8,0.8 1.8,1.2 2.9,1.2 1,0 2.1-0.4 2.9-1.2l53.9-53.9c1.7-1.6 1.7-4.2 0.1-5.8z' /%3E%3C/svg%3E");
}
```

- [You can check it in this CodePan](https://codepen.io/M1rotvorez/pen/eYYWpOK)
- [Here is information from Caniuse about mask-image](https://caniuse.com/#search=mask-image)
- [And here documentation about mask property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/mask-image)

Comment: Best answer imo. Well supported for all major browsers with -webkit prefix and much less code to achieve it.

Comment: Can't you store that long Data URI into another CSS variable and reuse it?

Answer (score 11):

Don't include svg as background, by doing that you don't have control over it's fill, instead try adding it inline in html and via css you can control the fill via css variable, please check the working example below, hope it helps :)

```css
:root {
  --primary-color: hsl(332, 61%, 78%);
}

div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}

.test {
  background: var(--primary-color);
}

.icon {
  color: var(--primary-color);
  fill: currentColor;
  width: 64px;
  height: 64px;
}
```

```html
<div class="test">
  Testing the css variable color
</div>
<svg class="icon" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 129 129">
  <path d="m121.3,34.6c-1.6-1.6-4.2-1.6-5.8,0l-51,51.1-51.1-51.1c-1.6-1.6-4.2-1.6-5.8,0-1.6,1.6-1.6,4.2 0,5.8l53.9,53.9c0.8,0.8 1.8,1.2 2.9,1.2 1,0 2.1-0.4 2.9-1.2l53.9-53.9c1.7-1.6 1.7-4.2 0.1-5.8z"/>
</svg>
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer! The reason I went the route of using SVG as a background was to try and replace the dropdown arrow in the select tag (sorry did not state that in the question/codepen!)... Not sure if using an actual SVG inside the tag would work out for me. But good to know that CSS variables would work in inline SVGs!

Comment: in that case use font icons, upload you desired svg file to https://icomoon.io/app/#/select app or select one from there Icons Library and generate the font, then u will be able to use it similar to fontawsome, then u will have control over the color. :)

Comment: fill: currentColor; <- where is that `currentColor` coming from?

Comment: @Bullsized `currentColor` is a CSS keyword / value that is the current color of that element or its parent's color.

Answer (score 4):

### Using the `<symbol>` tag and CSS variables

CSS variables inherit the `fill` property. Therefore, it is possible to assign (declare) a variable inside the `<symbol>` tag, the value of which can be subsequently changed many times for each instance of the svg element.

```
<symbol id="monstr"> 
<rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="transparent" />
<path id="face" fill="var(--color-face)" d="M15.4,34.1L24,37l8.6-2.9c1.9-0.6,3-2.6,2.6-4.6L33,20H15l-2.2,9.5C12.3,31.5,13.5,33.5,15.4,34.1z"/>
<path  id="nose" fill="var(--color-nose)" d="M29,30l-3-3h-4l-3,3v7c0,1.1,0.9,2,2,2h6c1.1,0,2-0.9,2-2V30z"/>
```

Each `path`, `circle`, `ellips`, etc. can be assigned its own variable `fill = "var (- color-face)"` for fill and then change its value in the external style sheet:

`.monstr-colors { --color-face: #7986CB; --color-nose: #9FA8DA; }`

This technique creates powerful and flexible styling options for multicolor svg.

For example, for one state of an icon, we can assign one color scheme, and with `: hover`, assign a different color set to the same icon.

```
.monstr-colors {
  --color-face: #7986CB;
  --color-nose: #9FA8DA;
} 
.monstr-colors:hover {
  --color-face: #3F8B4D;  
  --color-nose: #58C46C;
)
```

Below is an example, according to your taste, the color scheme of the image is easily created and changed:

```css
.monstr-colors {
  --color-face: #7986CB;
  --color-nose: #9FA8DA;
  --color-hair-right:#3949AB;
  --color-hair-right2:#3949AB;
  --color-hair-left:#3949AB;
  --color-hair-left2:#3949AB;
  --color-eye-right:#1A237E;
  --color-pupil-right:#77006B;
  --color-eye-left:#1A237E;
  --color-pupil-left:#77006B;
  --color-ellipse1:#9FA8DA;
  --color-ellipse2:#7986CB;
  --color-ellipse3:#C5CAE9;
}  

.monstr-colors:hover {
  --color-face: #3F8B4D;  
  --color-nose: #58C46C;
  --color-hair-right:gold;
  --color-hair-right2:#FFBB00;
  --color-hair-left:gold;
  --color-hair-left2:#FFBB00;
  --color-eye-right:#77006B;
  --color-pupil-right:#FF4151;
  --color-eye-left:#77006B;
  --color-pupil-left:#FF4151;
  --color-ellipse1:#FFDD00;
  --color-ellipse2:#C1A700;
  --color-ellipse3:#FFEE7D;
}
```

```html
<svg  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1"  width="192" height="192" viewBox="0 0 48 48" > 
<symbol id="monstr"> 
<rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="transparent" />
<path id="face" fill="var(--color-face)" d="M15.4,34.1L24,37l8.6-2.9c1.9-0.6,3-2.6,2.6-4.6L33,20H15l-2.2,9.5C12.3,31.5,13.5,33.5,15.4,34.1z"/>
<path  id="nose" fill="var(--color-nose)" d="M29,30l-3-3h-4l-3,3v7c0,1.1,0.9,2,2,2h6c1.1,0,2-0.9,2-2V30z"/>


    <path id="hair-right" fill="var(--color-hair-right)" d="M31,7c-0.5,0-1,0.4-1,1c0,0,0,0,0,0c-0.4,0-0.8,0.2-0.9,0.6c-0.2,0.5,0,1.1,0.6,1.3   C30,10.1,40,14.4,40,32.4V37c0,0.6,0.4,1,1,1s1-0.4,1-1v-4.6c0-14.4-6.1-20.7-9.5-23.1C35.9,10.3,44,14.7,44,34c0,0.6,0.4,1,1,1   s1-0.4,1-1C46,7.7,31.6,7,31,7z"/>
    <path id="hair-right2" fill="var(--color-hair-right2)" d="M29.5,10.1c-0.5-0.3-1.1-0.1-1.3,0.4c-0.3,0.5-0.1,1.1,0.4,1.4c0.1,0,7.5,4.3,7.5,20.1v8c0,0.6,0.4,1,1,1   s1-0.4,1-1v-8C38,14.9,29.8,10.3,29.5,10.1z"/>
    <path id="hair-left" fill="var(--color-hair-left)" d="M18.4,9.9c0.5-0.2,0.8-0.8,0.6-1.3C18.8,8.2,18.4,8,18,8c0,0,0,0,0,0c0-0.6-0.5-1-1-1C16.4,7,2,7.7,2,34   c0,0.6,0.4,1,1,1s1-0.4,1-1c0-19.6,8.1-23.8,11.6-24.7C12.2,11.6,6,17.9,6,32.4V37c0,0.6,0.4,1,1,1s1-0.4,1-1v-4.6   C8,14.4,18,10.1,18.4,9.9z"/>
    <path id="hair-left" fill="var(--color-hair-left2)" d="M18.5,10.1C18.2,10.3,10,14.9,10,32v8c0,0.6,0.4,1,1,1s1-0.4,1-1v-8c0-15.8,7.4-20.1,7.5-20.1   c0.5-0.3,0.7-0.9,0.4-1.4C19.6,10,19,9.9,18.5,10.1z"/>

<path id="eye-right" fill="var(--color-eye-right)" d="M25,24.9c0,0,0.2,1.3,0.6,1.7s3.3,2.5,5.9-0.9c1.2-1.5,0.6-3.8,0.6-3.8S29.4,24.1,25,24.9z"/>
<circle id="pupil-right" cx="28" cy="25" r="1.5" fill="var(--color-pupil-right)" />
<path id="eye-left" fill="var(--color-eye-left)" d="M15.8,21.8c0,0-0.6,2.3,0.6,3.8c2.6,3.4,5.5,1.4,5.9,0.9c0.4-0.4,0.6-1.7,0.6-1.7  C18.6,24.1,15.8,21.8,15.8,21.8z"/> 
<circle id="pupil-left" fill="var(--color-pupil-left)" cx="20" cy="25" r="1.5" fill="red" />
<ellipse  id="ellipse1" fill="var(--color-ellipse1)" cx="24" cy="15" rx="12" ry="10"/>
<ellipse id="ellipse2" fill="var(--color-ellipse2)" cx="24" cy="13.8" rx="10" ry="7.8"/>
<ellipse id="ellipse3" fill="var(--color-ellipse3)" cx="24.2" cy="12.2" rx="8" ry="6.2"/> 

</symbol> 
 <svg class="monstr-colors">
  <use  xlink:href="#monstr" />
 </svg>
</svg>
```

### Below is a combined example with styling three instances of the same image.

Each instance of the created `<use xlink: href = "# monstr"/>` has its own color scheme, which is linked to the nested svg class.

```
<div class="container">
<svg class="color-monstr">
<use xlink:href="#monstr" transform="scale(3)" />
</svg> 
 </div>
<div class="container2">
<svg class="color-monstr2">
<use xlink:href="#monstr" transform="scale(2)"  />
</svg> 
</div> 

<div class="container3">
<svg class="color-monstr3">
<use xlink:href="#monstr" transform="scale(3)"  />
</svg> 
</div>
```

***With `:hover`, each instance replaces the color scheme with the color scheme of the adjacent instance.***

```css
.parent {
position:relative;
}
.container {
width:400px;
height:400px;
position:absolute;
top:0;
} 
.container2 {
position: absolute;
top:0;
left:150px;

} 

.container3 {
position: absolute;
top:0;
left:240px;

} 

.color-monstr {
  --color-ears: #459E48;
  --color-horn-right: #388E3C;
  --color-horn-left: #388E3C;
  --color-face:#4CAF50;
  --circle-horn-left:#8BC34A;
  --circle-horn-right:#8BC34A;
  --eye-right:#FFF9C4;
  --eye-left:#FFF9C4;
  --pupil-right:#263238;
  --pupil-left:#263238;
  --mouth:#173027;
  }  
  
  .color-monstr:hover {
  --color-ears: #504F7A;
  --color-horn-right: #504FF6;
  --color-horn-left: #504FF6;
  --color-face:#807FC4;
  --circle-horn-left:#FF00AE;
  --circle-horn-right:#FF00AE;
  --eye-right:#FFDBF4;
  --eye-left:#FFDBF4;
  --pupil-right:#263238;
  --pupil-left:#263238;
  --mouth:#FFDBF4;
  }  
  
  .color-monstr2 {
  --color-ears: #504F7A;
  --color-horn-right: #504FF6;
  --color-horn-left: #504FF6;
  --color-face:#807FC4;
  --circle-horn-left:#FF00AE;
  --circle-horn-right:#FF00AE;
  --eye-right:#FFDBF4;
  --eye-left:#FFDBF4;
  --pupil-right:#263238;
  --pupil-left:#263238;
  --mouth:#FFDBF4;
  }   
  
  .color-monstr2:hover {
  --color-ears: #770051;
  --color-horn-right: #388E3C;
  --color-horn-left: #388E3C;
  --color-face:#FFDD00;
  --circle-horn-left:#D0FF00;
  --circle-horn-right:#A0C400;
  --eye-right:#FFF9C4;
  --eye-left:#FFF9C4;
  --pupil-right:#263238;
  --pupil-left:#263238;
  --mouth:#FFF9C4;
  
  }  
  
  .color-monstr3 {
  --color-ears: #770051;
  --color-horn-right: #388E3C;
  --color-horn-left: #388E3C;
  --color-face:#FFDD00;
  --circle-horn-left:#D0FF00;
  --circle-horn-right:#A0C400;
  --eye-right:#FFF9C4;
  --eye-left:#FFF9C4;
  --pupil-right:#263238;
  --pupil-left:#263238;
  --mouth:#FFF9C4;
  } 
  
  .color-monstr3:hover {
  --color-ears: #459E48;
  --color-horn-right: #388E3C;
  --color-horn-left: #388E3C;
  --color-face:#4CAF50;
  --circle-horn-left:#8BC34A;
  --circle-horn-right:#8BC34A;
  --eye-right:#FFF9C4;
  --eye-left:#FFF9C4;
  --pupil-right:#263238;
  --pupil-left:#263238;
  --mouth:#173027;
  }
```

```html
<div class="parent">
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"   viewBox="0 0 48 48" > 
<symbol id="monstr">

<path id="ears"
 fill="var(--color-ears)"
  d="M12,31c-2.3,0-3.7-3.2-4-5c0.7-1.3,3.3-2,4-2c5.7-2.4,17.8-2.9,24,0c0.7,0,3.3,0.7,4,2c-0.3,1.8-1.7,5-4,5  C33.6,32.8,14.7,34.2,12,31z"/>
<g>
    <path id="horn-right"
   fill="var(--color-horn-right)" d="M40,8c-0.6,0-1,0.4-1,1c0,2.7-3.3,5-6,5c-0.6,0-1,0.4-1,1s0.4,1,1,1c3.7,0,8-3.1,8-7C41,8.4,40.6,8,40,8z"/>
    <path id="horn-left"
   fill="var(--color-horn-left)" d="M8,8c0.6,0,1,0.4,1,1c0,2.7,3.3,5,6,5c0.6,0,1,0.4,1,1s-0.4,1-1,1c-3.7,0-8-3.1-8-7C7,8.4,7.4,8,8,8z"/>
</g>
<path id="face"
 fill="var(--color-face)" d="M12,31v-7c0-9.2,5.3-16,12-16s12,6.8,12,16v7c-1.2,5.6-7,12-12,12S13.2,36.6,12,31z"/>
<g>
    <circle id="circle-horn-left" fill="var(--circle-horn-left)" cx="8" cy="9" r="3"/>
    <circle id="circle-horn-right" fill="var(--circle-horn-right)" cx="40" cy="9" r="3"/>
</g>
<g>
    <ellipse id="eye-right" fill="var(--eye-right)" cx="29" cy="26" rx="2" ry="4"/>
    <ellipse id="eye-left" fill="var(--eye-left)" cx="19" cy="26" rx="2" ry="4"/>
</g>
<g>
    <circle id="pupil-right" fill="var(--pupil-right)" cx="29" cy="27" r="1"/>
    <circle id="pupil-left" fill="var(--pupil-left)" cx="19" cy="27" r="1"/>
</g>
<path id="mouth" fill="var(--mouth)" d="M24,33c-4,0-5.8,3-5.8,3s2.6,0,5.8,0s5.8,0,5.8,0S28,33,24,33z"/>
</symbol> 
</svg>


<div class="container">
<svg class="color-monstr">
<use xlink:href="#monstr" transform="scale(3)" />
</svg> 
 </div>
<div class="container2">
<svg class="color-monstr2">
<use xlink:href="#monstr" transform="scale(2)"  />
</svg> 
</div> 

<div class="container3">
<svg class="color-monstr3">
<use xlink:href="#monstr" transform="scale(3)"  />
</svg> 
</div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

I stumbled upon this for a very similar case and want to share a completely different approach.

Use the css multi background feature ([MDN Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Backgrounds_and_Borders/Using_multiple_backgrounds))

First you need to make the part of your svg that you want to color transparent with `fill="transparent"`
Now you can just specify multiple backgrounds, where one can be your variable, for example

```css
body {
    background: url('path/to/your/svg/or/data-url'), var(--background);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can not control the color of an externally included SVG directly with a CSS custom property (CSS variable), but you can manipulate the color when it has a class with the help of JS which also helps when you have a color toggling like a dark mode.

Here is how I color my SVGs. As Inline SVGs have a bitter taste on readability of the rest of the code and adding them as background or mask, they can not be colored by a **dark theme switch**. Include them externally and load them inside an HTML object:

```
<object id="background-anim" class="svg" aria-hidden="true" data="./media/Background-fluid-lines-anim.svg" type="image/svg+xml"></object>
```

This SVG is now added externally.
To set the colors you need to set for the desired colors a class ***inside of the SVG***.

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 1920 1080">
  <defs>
    <style>
        .svg-element__clrText{
            fill:rgb(255,255,255);
        }
        .svg-element__clrPrimary{
            fill:rgb(155,155,155);
        }
        .svg-element__clrBackground{
            fill:rgb(55,55,55);
        }
    </style>
  </defs>
  <path class="svg-element__clrText"></path>
</svg>
```

In your paths, you will set those classes to the desired elements that should adapt colors.
Now you will manipulate those fill values with JavaScript and add the correct CSS Custom Porperties:

```
/*Optional: Listening to the clicked switch if you have one*/
document.querySelectorAll('.theme-toggle').forEach((toggle) => {
   toggle.addEventListener('click', () => themeToggle);
});
window.themeToggle = function themeToggle() {
   document.documentElement.classList.toggle('darkMode');
   //this .darkmode{} class changes the values of my variables set to white mode in the ':root{}' in the css file
   loadTheme()
}
function loadTheme(){
   /* For loading more than just the colors */
   loadThemeIcon();
   loadSVGColors();
}

/* Now here comes the important part */
function loadSVGColors() {
   const svgs = document.querySelectorAll('.svg'); //getting NodeList of SVGs
   const style = getComputedStyle(document.body), //getting CSS variables inside of js
   svgs.forEach(svg => {
               element = svg.contentDocument; //get the actual svg that is loaded into the object element
         const clrText = svg.querySelectorAll('.svg-element__textClr'), //searching inside of the SVG after my classes
         textClr.forEach(element => { //NodeList to Array
              element.style.fill = style.getPropertyValue('--clr-text');//whatever variables you have set or you can toggle a class that has only this css variable inside
         });

         /* [...and so on]*/
         const primeClr = element.querySelectorAll('.svg-element__primeClr');
         primeClr.forEach(e => {
              e.style.fill = style.getPropertyValue('--clr-primary');
         });
   });
}
```

I guess there is a better performance when you add the SVGs inside the HTML with `fill: var(--clr-text)`, however after having 50kb of code per SVG leads to lots of scrolling

I know this goes further than the question but I would have been glad to find this before under these SO posts.

Answer (score -2):

```
<path class="class-name"/>

:root {
   --color : #123456;
}
.class-name {
   fill : var(--color)
}
```

try this

Comment: While this code may provide a solution to the question, it's better to add context as to why/how it works. This can help future users learn and eventually apply that knowledge to their own code. You are also likely to have positive feedback/upvotes from users, when the code is explained.

Answer (score -4):

If you need to control only one color, you can use `currentColor` keyword in the `fill` property and change it through css `color` property.

```
.icon {
  color: var(--primary-color);
  background: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' viewBox='0 0 129 129'%3E%3Cpath d='m121.3,34.6c-1.6-1.6-4.2-1.6-5.8,0l-51,51.1-51.1-51.1c-1.6-1.6-4.2-1.6-5.8,0-1.6,1.6-1.6,4.2 0,5.8l53.9,53.9c0.8,0.8 1.8,1.2 2.9,1.2 1,0 2.1-0.4 2.9-1.2l53.9-53.9c1.7-1.6 1.7-4.2 0.1-5.8z' fill='currentColor' /%3E%3C/svg%3E");
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, `currentColor` doesn't work with url-encoded SVGs.