# Using CSS Variables (custom properties) in a Pseudo-class

Tags: css, angular, pseudo-class, renderer

I have tried the below code. But its not working.

```
    .coin:before{
       background-image:var(--dynamic-image);
     }
```

And I want to pass --dynamic-image from a method inside component. I am using  Angular Renderer2 and the element that I want set background for is  this.flip.

```
    flipCoin() {
      this.renderer.setStyle(this.flip.nativeElement, '--dynamic-image' , "url('https://www.w3schools.com/howto/img_forest.jpg')");
    }
```

Am I doing anything wrong here ??

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42330075/is-there-a-way-to-interpolate-css-variables-with-url

Comment: Paulie_D does this mean we cannot use css variables for url ??

Comment: Yep...thats' exactly what it means.

Comment: if you know any other alternative approach to meet my requirement..let me know ?

Comment: @Paulie_D we can use them for url when it's not inside the *url* like this case